# 2-state HMM / ARMA process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, time-series

I have issues with this problem:

Let $\{X_t, t\in \Bbb N\}$ be a 2-state stationary Markov chain, with transition $M$ (and $M(1,2)\neq 0 \neq M(2,1)$), let $\{W_t, t\in \Bbb N\}$ be a strong Gaussian white noise.

Let $$
Y_t = b_{X_t} + \sigma_{X_t} W_t
$$
How to prove that $\{Y_t, t\in \Bbb N\}$ is an ARMA(1,1) process?

Comment: I thought that cross-posting has to be avoided.

Comment: You're right, it should be avoided. We can try try get a moderator to migrate it if you want.

Comment: So you have a Markov chain $X_t$ and as you describe the transition matrix $M$ it is possible to go from state $1$ to $2$ and back. Is this really enough info to prove that $Y_t$ solves $Y_t = a Y_{t-1} + b W_{t-1} + W_t$, the ARMA(1,1) representation?

Comment: I think it is enough to prove that it is the stationnary solution of this equation, indeed. One way suggested seems to look at the ACF of $Y$.